# How can I save all dictionary to a CSV file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

How can I save these dictionaries' keys as columns and values as rows to CSV?

```
    {'Full Name': None, 'Nick Name': None, 'profession': 'Model, 
    Actress', 'Height': 'in centimeters- 165 cm, in meters- 1.65 m, 
    in feet & inches- 5’ 5”', 'Weight': None}
    {'Full Name': None, 'Nick Name': 'Chikoo, Run Machine', 
    'profession': 'Indian Cricketer (Batsman)', 'Height': 'in 
    centimeters- 175 cm, in meters- 1.75 m, in Feet Inches- 5’ 9”', 
    'Weight': None}
    {'Full Name': 'Amitabh Harivansh Rai Shrivastava', 'Nick Name': 
    'Munna, Big B, Angry Young Man, AB Sr., Amith, Shahenshah of 
    Bollywood', 'profession': 'Actor, TV Host, Former Politician', 
    'Height': 'in centimeters- 188 cm, in meters- 1.88 m, in Feet 
    Inches- 6’ 2” [2]@SrBachchan', 'Weight': None}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you have any errors? Also, please do not post images, please copy the text for the dict into this post. Thanks, and welcome! :)

Comment: I'd say how you generate the dicts is irrelevant. You have a number of dicts, and you want to turn them into one CSV. I believe my answer shows you how to do that. Good job on the requesting and scraping, though! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are looping over a set of URLs, downloading the HTML for each URL, scraping that HTML and making into a dict.

You could just collect each dict, and arrive at something like `all_dicts`, as I have shown:

```py
import csv

all_dicts = []

# for url in urllist:
    # request url
    # scrape html from url
    # somehow you convert scraped html to a dict, let's call it new_dict
    # all_dicts.append(new_dict)

# And, now you have all the dictionaries, and it looks something like this:
all_dicts = [
    {'Full Name': None, 'Nick Name': None, 'profession': 'Model, Actress',
        'Height': 'in centimeters- 165 cm, in meters- 1.65 m, in feet & inches- 5’ 5”', 'Weight': None},
    {'Full Name': None, 'Nick Name': 'Chikoo, Run Machine',
        'profession': 'Indian Cricketer (Batsman)', 'Height': 'in centimeters- 175 cm, in meters- 1.75 m, in Feet Inches- 5’ 9”', 'Weight': None},
    {'Full Name': 'Amitabh Harivansh Rai Shrivastava', 'Nick Name': 'Munna, Big B, Angry Young Man, AB Sr., Amith, Shahenshah of Bollywood',
        'profession': 'Actor, TV Host, Former Politician', 'Height': 'in centimeters- 188 cm, in meters- 1.88 m, in Feet Inches- 6’ 2” [2]@SrBachchan', 'Weight': None},
    # ... more of your dicts
]

# And then you move on to writing all_dicts
with open('my.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=all_dicts[0].keys())
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(all_dicts)
```

Comment: Hey @Zach Young, Thanks for your quick response. I just updated my question with details.

Comment: it's not working!

Comment: What about my code, or setup, is wrong? Does **my.csv** in my answer look correct? I copied the output from your `print(newdicts)` exactly (except for having to add commas between each dict, and having to fix all the line breaks).

Comment: Your way is correct what you did. but the problem is you added all of the dictionaries to a list. If you checked my whole code It's not possible for me. I am looking for 2 solutions. Is there any way, that I can write all of the dictionaries to CSV without adding a list? Or how can I put all of my dictionaries on the list?

Comment: I have read your code, and I do not understand what is impossible for you. I see you have the ability to make some small changes to your code and collect each dict as it is created, then write them all at once. You haven't said why you cannot do that. I've updated my post to try and reflect the idea of your code.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working fine.